# Notepad++ auto-queue replacement

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Is there anyway to auto-queue a statement to replace every time you open a new file?

Example:

`.*[ing|;]$`

This statement replaces lines ending in ING, is there a way to queue a list of these to replace all in mass?

Example of list:

```
.*[ing|;]$
.*[s|;]$
.*[ly|;]$
.*[er|;]$
.*[ed|;]$
.*[ment|;]$
.*[ic|;]$
.*[ship|;]$
```

Meaning I could just click a replace all button for every single one of these suffixes and add more suffixes to my list to purge word lists.

Comment: This sounds like a job for sed.

Comment: You can record macros. It may won't run automatically,  but you will need to press just one button to do all the replacements.